# Reading int value from char array after converting to void pointer

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build memory chunks of generic data types, but I'm getting garbage when printing the result.

```
void Read(void* _data, size_t _size, int _position) const
{
    char* data = new char[_size];
    memcpy(data, m_data + _position - _size, _size);
}

void Write(void* _data, size_t _size, int _position)
{
    char* data = new char[_size];
    memcpy(m_data + _position, data, _size);
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    Chunk c(10);
    int value = 10, result;

    c.Write(&value, sizeof(int), 0);
    c.Read(&result, sizeof(int), sizeof(int));
    cout << *((int *)result) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In C++ you should be utilizing templates if you want generics

Comment: Should you at least give the class declaration> Also should it be `void Chunk::Read` ...?

Comment: I'd assume this is an example you've simplified from something that's inside a class? Can't you just post the class? Half the variables are missing (like m_data in Read) or unused (_data in Read). This isn't really readable like that...

Answer (score 3):

"What am I doing wrong?" - Pretty much everything:

To begin with, both `Read` and `Write` functions end with a memory leak, as the allocated-memory pointed by the `data` local variable is "lost" (no one "knows" the address after the function returns).

In addition, what exactly are you expecting to get by casting `(int*)result`? It is most certainly not going to be a valid memory address which you can then safely dereference using `*((int*)result)`.

Comment: This sums it up nicely. Unless you're doing this for a learning exercise, there is also very little reason to ever do this. There are mechanisms/classes in the standard library that do most memory management for you. Nowadays with modern compilers (C++11), doing "new" and "delete" yourself is pretty much always unnecessarily dangerous. Use the features available to you.

Comment: Thanks @Creat, but you're telling all this to the wrong guy. The question is up there, not here :)

Comment: I know, I was hoping he'd read my comment together with your reply. I've already commented above as well, and thought commenting on what you'd written could help him further. Don't know how to do that other than with a comment on your answer...

Answer (score 0):

In your read function, the parameter `_data` is not used, so it won't modify anything. It should be:

```
void Read(void* _data, size_t _size, int _position) 
{
  memcpy(_data, m_data + _position - _size, _size);
}
```

Also, the code to output variable `result` doesn't make sense, should just be:

```
cout << result << endl;
```

As the program is not the complete program, I don't know if there're still other errors